# How can i access request headers in graphql query using java datafetcher environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I want to fetch a header value I am passing during a GraphQl Query call. Something like we can do prior in case of rest api
HttpServletRequest.getheader()

I wanted to fetch it from the dataFetchingEnvironment but the context fetched from this value did not get me any means to fetch the header values from request.

```
        try {
            GraphQLContext context =  env.getGraphQlContext();
            String Id= context.getHeader("headerkeyIpass"); 
// I know this method does not exist i am trying to paint a picture as to what i am asking
```

I do not intend to change the resolver method calls but any inputs to improve my code would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said `getHttpServletRequest` does not exist on `DataFetchingEnvironment.getGraphQlContext()` when using the new official Spring 2.7 `spring-boot-starter-graphql` (not the [legacy GraphQL Java Kickstart](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart) ones).

Instead you can add an autowired `HttpServletRequest` request variable at the top of your controller and inside each query resolver it will be filled with the request context.

```
@Controller
public class SomeGraphQLController {
    ...

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request; // will be filled inside each @QueryResolver and @MutationResolver method.

    ...

    @QueryResolver
    public XXX yyyy() {
        ...
        try {
            String someHeader = request.getHeader("someHeader"); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [GraphQLContext](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.graphql-java/graphql-java-servlet/6.1.1/graphql/servlet/GraphQLContext.html) has method `getHttpServletRequest()` which returns

```
java.util.Optional<javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest>
```

So from there u can get the headers

```
GraphQLContext context =  env.getGraphQlContext();
HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest().get();
String Id= request.getHeader("headerkeyIpass");
```

If you are using the latest [graphql libraries](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet/releases/tag/v8.0.0) there are some breaking changed and you can get the headers from `GraphQLServletContext` as shown [here](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/456)

```
GraphQLServletContext graphQLServletContext = (GraphQLServletContext) env.getContext();
    
String user = graphQLServletContext.getHttpServletRequest().getHeader("user");
```

Comment: I did use the below code to get the header value
```
    GraphQLServletContext context =  env.getContext();
     HttpServletRequest request=context.getHttpServletRequest();
    String Id= request.getHeader("headerkeyIpass"); 
```
But the DataFetcherEnvironement.getContext is deprecated

The above code

HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest().get();

doesn't work since the getHttpServletRequest does not exist for the GraphQLContext but GraphQLServletContext does have that. Now can we get the GraphQLServletContext from the DataFetching env?

Comment: This does not work. context.getHttpServletRequest() doesn't exist on graphQlContext.

Comment: the breaking changes are that env.getContext() is deprecated. I am actually trying to get rid of it, but I didn't find how.